# QT Creator fails to build when TEMPLATE=subdirs is added

Tags: qt, projects-and-solutions, qt-creator

I'm new to QT Creator.  I want to create a QT project with an exe and a static lib.

If I create the exe project first, it builds/rebuilds fine for every build configuration.

However, when i add `TEMPLATE = subdirs` to the end of the .pro file it stops building correctly.  But it appears that is necessary to add static libs to the project. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to have a .pro file with TEMPLATE = subdirs on the toplevel and then the executable in one subdirectory and the library in another. Add both directories to SUBDIRS.

AFAIK it is not (easily) possible with qmake to build something and also recurse in one .pro file.

I am not sure about Qt Creator support, but it is easy to create the TEMPLATE = subdirs .pro file by hand.

Comment: That pretty much answers my question. Would you suggest creating an empty qt project for the top level then?  In Visual Studio terms, this would act as the sln i think.

Answer (score 0):

edit:

I'm sorry, I did not understand what you are trying to do, can you explain better?

Does this help:

> The template can be overridden by specifying a new template type with the -t command line option. This overrides the template type after the .pro file has been processed. With .pro files that use the template type to determine how the project is built, it is necessary to declare TEMPLATE on the command line rather than use the -t option.

from [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-variable-reference.html#template)